# How Can I remove "1 empty item" from the json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

The sample json object. I tried to remove all "-", "N/A", and "" from this JSON object.

```
{
  name: { first: 'Robert', middle: '', last: 'Smith' },
  age: 25,
  DOB: '-',
  hobbies: [ 'running', 'coding', '-' ],
  education: { highschool: 'N/A', college: 'Yale' }
}
```

I did something like it. but couldn't manage to remove <1 empty item> from the array

```
{
  name: { first: 'Robert', last: 'Smith' },
  age: 25,
  hobbies: [ 'running', 'coding', <1 empty item> ],
  education: { college: 'Yale' }
}
```

How can I remove the <1 empty item> from the json object.

This is my code

```
axios.get("https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/json-cleaning")
  .then((res) => {
    let parseData = res.data;

    const removeValue = (obj) => {
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => 
        
        // console.log(obj[k])
        (obj[k] && obj[k] === "-") && 
        delete obj[k] ||

        (obj[k] && typeof obj[k] === 'object')
        && removeValue(obj[k]) || 
        
        (!obj[k] && obj[k] !== undefined) && 
        delete obj[k] || 
        
        (obj[k] && obj[k] === "N/A") && 
        delete obj[k]


      );
      return obj
    }

    newData = removeValue(parseData)

    console.log(newData)
  })
```

Comment: and in case the array becomes empty, should it also be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `delete` is fine on objects, but for arrays, it will remove the property while keeping the array's `.length` the same. So, for example, `delete`-ing the 3rd item of an array of length 3 will result in an array with two array-indexed properties (0 and 1), but keep its length of 3.

Check if the object is an array. If it's an array, `.filter` instead.

```js
const payload = {
  name: { first: 'Robert', middle: '', last: 'Smith' },
  age: 25,
  DOB: '-',
  hobbies: [ 'running', 'coding', '-' ],
  education: { highschool: 'N/A', college: 'Yale' }
};
const isGoodValue = val => val && val !== '-' && val !== 'N/A';

const removeBadValues = (obj) => {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    return obj
      .filter(isGoodValue)
      .map(removeBadValues);
  }
  if (typeof obj === 'object') {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      if (!isGoodValue(value)) {
        delete obj[key];
      } else {
        obj[key] = removeBadValues(value);
      }
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
const newData = removeBadValues(payload)
console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
obj.hobbies.splice(obj.hobbies.indexOf('-'), 1);
```

Where obj is the object you pass in.

Answer (score 1):

use [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

complete code (recursive) with also empty array or empty object removal

```js
const data_row = 
  { name      : { first: 'Robert', middle: '', last: 'Smith'} 
  , age       : 25
  , DOB       : '-'
  , hobbies   : [ 'running', 'coding', '-'] 
  , education : { highschool: 'N/A', college: 'Yale'} 
  } 
     
clearner( data_row )
console.log( data_row )


function clearner( obj )
  {
  const bad = ['-', 'N/A',  '']
  
  for (prop in obj)  
    {
    switch (Array.isArray(obj[prop]) ? 'array' : typeof obj[prop])
      {
      case 'array':
        for (let i=obj[prop].length;i--;)
          if ( bad.includes( obj[prop][i] ))
            obj[prop].splice(i,1); 
        break;
      case 'string':
        if (bad.includes( obj[prop] ))
          delete obj[prop]
        break;
      case 'object':
        clearner( obj[prop] )
        break;
      } 
    if ( obj[prop] && obj[prop].length === 0 )  // empty array or empty object removal
      delete obj[prop]  
  } }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using JSON [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) with [`replacer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter) argument, Using this method also means the replacement is done to all nested keys within nested objects:

```js
let obj = {
  name: { first: "Robert", middle: "", last: "Smith" },
  age: 25,
  DOB: "-",
  hobbies: ["running", "coding", "-"],
  education: { highschool: "N/A", college: "Yale" },
};
function replacer(key, value) {
  if (value === "N/A" || value === "") {
    return undefined;
  } else if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    return value.filter((el) => el != "-");
  }
  return value;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, replacer, 4));
```

**Note:** Use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to turn it back into an object.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var test = {
  DOB: '-',
  test2: 'somestring',
  test3: 3,
}

function clean(obj) {
  for (var propName in obj) {
    if (obj[propName] === '-' || obj[propName] === undefined) {
      delete obj[propName];
    }
  }
  return obj
}

console.log(test);
console.log(clean(test));
```